# Why django collectstatic is not finding my css

Tags: django

I am struggling with django static files. I want to link "screen.css" stored in "all_statics/css" folder to "index.html".

Here is my html file :

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Gwendolyn:wght@700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="{% static '/css/screen.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" >
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Test</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

In my settings.py, I have set these variables :

```
STATIC_URL = 'static/'

STATICFILES_DIR = [
    BASE_DIR / 'all_statics',
]

STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'static'
```

Here is my project structure :
[Project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PdafK.png)

When I run `python manage.py collectstatic` , the static files from admin app is copied to static folder, but not the files from 'all_statics' .

When I run `python manage.py runserver` and browse to the index page, I see that the css can't be found (404) :

```
[18/Jan/2022 11:30:26] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 308
[18/Jan/2022 11:30:27] "GET /static/css/screen.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1801
```

When I run  `python .\manage.py findstatic css/screen.css` I get : `No matching file found for 'css/screen.css'.`

I have created a sample project to show my problem. You can clone it from https://github.com/doolieSoft/django_project.git .

Do you have an idea why my css can't be found ?

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Your setting is misspelled, should be `STATICFILES_DIRS` not `STATIFFILES_DIR`

Comment: I have corrected it but it is still the same. Project updated on my github.

Comment: You're still missing an `S` at the end of the setting name

Comment: Hooo !! Finally, I must be tired ! Thanks for your help !